# Some of the .tif files downloaded with geemap are flipped vertically

Tags: gdal, google-earth-engine, geotiff-tiff, geemap

I have downloaded some images from Google Earth Engine, using Geemap library using this code:

```
geemap.download_ee_image(s1_img_vv, "s1_img.tif",crs='EPSG:4326', scale=10,region = r_roi)

geemap.download_ee_image(s2_img_B2_5,"s2_img.tif",crs='EPSG:4326', scale=10,region = r_roi)
```

The `s1` images are a `mean()` over an ImageCollection and the `s2` images are sometimes `median()` or `first()` of the s2 ImageCollection.

Although I am encountering a really weird problem, some of the downloaded images(of both S1 and S2), in a random manner, are flipped vertically, when reading them as an `numpy.array` with `GDAL`, or reading them using `skitimage.io.imread()`, or `tifffile.imread()`

When opening these images with `QGIS`, all of them are fine and in the correct direction.

I rolled back all of these libraries, to the older versions, and the problem is still there.

I also used the older version of `geemap` and `geedim`, and still nothing.

I am wondering whether this problem is caused by something in the `metadata` of these images, that makes the `read()` functions read them vertically flipped.

Or is there a problem with geemap or geedim, that somehow download's these images in this way? When using `geedim==1.5.0` and `geemap==0.17.0` I am getting these warnings:

```
WARNING:rasterio._env:CPLE_NotSupported in 'None' is an unexpected value for PHOTOMETRIC creation option of type string-select.
```

```
WARNING:rasterio._env:CPLE_IllegalArg in /005_aguasclaras_adj_goiania21.tif: PHOTOMETRIC=None value not recognised, ignoring.  Set the Photometric Interpretation as MINISBLACK.
```

[This is the link to the original file of the plotted images](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1zK_nfdycNsRzi8WPrU2QEZ-xWtkOvjEx?usp=sharing)

[image: s1 images in 2017, 2019, and 2021]
Notice how the image in 2021 is flipped, this combination is different for each roi.

Answer (score 1):

Well, after going through all the commits made to `geemap` and `geedim` in the past 6 months I can definitely say this is not a problem with `geemap`, but this might be a bug in `geedim`, but I couldn't pinpoint a specific change.
I will write an issue on their repo when I'm confident this is a bug on their side.

But for a simple solution, I'll try to explain the workarounds that worked for me:

##### Using `ee_export_image` instead of `download_ee_image`

If the images you are trying to download are not too large, this is will work fine since this function does not use `geedim`.

```
geemap.ee_export_image(img, "image.tif", crs='EPSG:4326', scale=10, region=roi)
```

##### Using `EPSG:3857` instead of `EPSG:4326`

Using this projection seems to resolve the problem for me.

##### Adding an extra band to the image indicating the correct direction

This is absolutely a bad code, with a lot of extra bytes of download from EE servers.
But by adding a constant zero band, with a few pixels on the top left corner being 1 to the `ee.Image`, I could figure out whether my image is flipped or not after the download, then fixed them using `np.flip`

---

Besides these methods,

I tried reprojecting the image before downloading and it didn't work.

A hardcoded `crs_transfrom` with a `y_scale` being negative doesn't work either since the images are flipped "some" of the time and not always.

Hope this helps.